# Bootstrap3 nav bar not working once site is published

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, css

I've developed a site that when I debugged it in visual studio 2012, everything worked fine. After publishing though, my nav drop downs aren't working. It looks like its just putting a # at the end of the current url. I'm using a Master/Content page setup, from what I can tell it looks like a jquery issue. Not sure how to fix the problem though. Any help would be appreciated.

These are in the master page header:

```
<link href="../Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="../Content/external-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Mast Page body:

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <div class="container">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default" id="navbar" role="navigation">

                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="Home.aspx">
                        <img src="Images/XXXX.png" class="img-responsive" alt="logo" />
                    </a>
                </div>

                <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="Home.aspx">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Products & Services <b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="Consulting.aspx">Consulting</a></li>
                                <li><a href="SpaceFiller.aspx">Space Filler</a></li>
                                <li><a href="Documentation.aspx">Product Documentation</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Careers <b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="Company.aspx">Company</a></li>
                                <li><a href="Openings.aspx">Openings</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <%--<li><a href="Customer.aspx">Customer Portal</a></li>--%>
                        <li><a href="Contact.aspx">Contact Us</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
                <!-- /.container-fluid -->
            </nav>
        </div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
</form>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#sidebar').affix({
            offset: {
                top: 290
            }
        });

        var $body = $(document.body);
        var navHeight = $('.navbar').outerHeight(true) + 10;

        $body.scrollspy({
            target: '#leftCol',
            offset: navHeight
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: any errors in the console?

Comment: No, no errors. The only thing I can tell is that none of the jquery functionality is working at all. Carousels, affix.js, navbar dropdowns, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All that needed to be done was to remove the forward slash in front at the beginning of "Scripts/..." on the two jquery script references at the bottom of the master page. Problem solved.

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```